# Can I list all VTable pointers from a core dump?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb

I have a core dump of a C++ program which was built and run with the GNU toolchain. I can reproduce the executable *maybe*. How can I find a list of all the vtable pointers, by class name?

Answer (score 3):

You can get vtable layouts using `-fdump-class-hierarchy` when compiling. This might help when inspecting objects. You may need `set print vtbl on` in gdb.